# Remove comma from columns in a file if it is at the end

Tags: text-processing, perl, columns

I have a tab separated file contain 19 columns, some of these columns contain comma at the end. I want to removed these comma from all columns if it is at the end.
Example:

```
c1   c2   c3   c4   c5  
re,  f,f   d,f,  gf   mk
df   df,  df   dl,  df,
```

The result should be and saved in the same file

```
c1   c2    c3    c4   c5  
re   f,f   d,f   gf   mk
df   df    df    dl   df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
perl -i -pe 's/,(\t|$)/$1/g' file
```

That will remove any commas followed by a space, a tab or a newline.

For other field delimiters, for example `:`, use:

```
perl -i -F: -lane 's/,$// for @F; print join ":",@F' file
```

**These commands will change the original file**, remove the `-i` to test it first.

Answer (score 2):

To remove a single comma at the end of each field:

```
perl -i -pe 's/,(\t|$)/$1/g' myfile
```

`(\t|$)` matches either a tab or the end of the line. `s/…/…/g` replaces every occurrence of the pattern (here, `,(\t|$)`) by the given replacement text (here, `$1`, meaning the part of the pattern that's inside parentheses). Fields that don't end with a comma aren't matched by the pattern so they're printed out without modification.

The [`-p` option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-p*) instructs Perl to apply the given expression to each input line and print out the modified line. The [`-i` option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*%5b_extension_%5d) causes the input file to be replaced by the resulting output.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some awesome lookaround stuffs..

```
perl -i -pe 's/,(?=\t|$)//g' file
```

or

```
perl -i -pe 's/,(?!\S)//g' file
```

or

Using Non-Word boundary..

```
perl -i -pe 's/,\B//g' file
```